# How to create nested child on firebase android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[Solved. I solved it myself]
Tips: if you want to access a child in the firebase realtime database for collecting data and then by using that data u store or upload something at that child on the firebase realtime database again, then you can't access it. Either u have to create another child or u must not use that child. (I don't no the actual solution but It works for me)] 
I want to create a child under the reference of the user phone number. That child will store one or more childs. These child will be called "serialNo" of the item. And under serialNo child, the item name and amount of piece will store. I want to create like this:

[image: The desire Firebase Structure]

[N: B: I've created this on firebase directly, not by my application.]

But when I put my data object as .setValue(dtObject) the previous one will always be replaced.
["orderNo: 1" child was replaced by "orderNo: 2" child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqiN1.png)

I also use .updateChildren(dtMap) but everytime previous orderNo child was replaced.

My Code of confirm Fragment(from where I upload):

```
package com.binarysoftwareltd.airaid;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AddressFragment extends Fragment {
private int orderNo = 1;
private int orderSerial = 0;
private DatabaseReference dbReference, dbr;
private static final String STATE_USER = "user";
private String mUser;
private View oldView;
private TextView numWarning;
private EditText nameField, phoneField, areaField, addressField, 
detailsField;
private CardView confirmCV;
private int len;
private String nameOfPerson, phoneNumber, areaName, addressOfOrder, 
detailsOfOrder;
private int[] serialNos = new int[100];
private String[] names = new String[100];
private int[] pieces = new int[100];
private String imageUri;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mUser = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_USER);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new 
instance
        mUser = "NewUser";
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString(STATE_USER, mUser);
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (oldView != null) {
        return oldView;
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_address, container, 
false);
    initializeAll(v);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        len = bundle.getInt("cValue");
        imageUri = bundle.getString("imgUri");
        serialNos = bundle.getIntArray("mSerialNos");
        names = bundle.getStringArray("mNames");
        pieces = bundle.getIntArray("mPieces");
    }
    confirmCV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            collectAllData();
            if (!phoneNumber.equals("")) {
                checkOrderSerial();
            } else {
                phoneField.requestFocus();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), orderSerial, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    oldView = v;
    return v;
}

private void checkOrderSerial() {
dbr=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(phoneNumber). 
child("currentOrderSerial");
    dbr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Integer value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            if (value != null)
                orderSerial = value;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    showConfirmDialog();
}

private void showConfirmDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    alb.setIcon(R.drawable.question);
    alb.setTitle("Confirm");
    alb.setMessage("Are you sure want to order?");
    alb.setPositiveButton(R.string.exit_no, new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alb.setNegativeButton(R.string.exit_yes, new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            setOrderSerial();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog ald = alb.create();
    ald.show();
}

private void setOrderSerial() {
    dbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(phoneNumber);
    if (orderNo <= orderSerial) {
        orderNo = orderSerial;
        orderNo += 1;
    }
    OrderSerial osObject = new OrderSerial(orderNo);
    dbr.setValue(osObject);
    uploadAllData();
}

private void uploadAllData() {
    dbReference = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(phoneNumber).child("orderNo: 
"+orderNo);
    DataTemplate dtObject;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (pieces[i] != 0) {
            dtObject = new DataTemplate(names[i],pieces[i]);
            dbReference.child("serialNo: 
"+serialNos[i]).setValue(dtObject);
        }
    }
}

private void collectAllData() {
    nameOfPerson = nameField.getText().toString();
    phoneNumber = phoneField.getText().toString();
    areaName = areaField.getText().toString();
    addressOfOrder = addressField.getText().toString();
    detailsOfOrder = detailsField.getText().toString();
}

private void initializeAll(View v) {
    numWarning = v.findViewById(R.id.numWarning);
    nameField = v.findViewById(R.id.nameField);
    phoneField = v.findViewById(R.id.phoneField);
    areaField = v.findViewById(R.id.areaField);
    addressField = v.findViewById(R.id.addressField);
    detailsField = v.findViewById(R.id.detailsField);
    confirmCV = v.findViewById(R.id.confirmCV);
}
}
```

My OrderSerial Class::

```
package com.binarysoftwareltd.airaid;

public class OrderSerial {

private int currentOrderSerial;

public OrderSerial() {

}

public OrderSerial(int currentOrderSerial) {
    this.currentOrderSerial = currentOrderSerial;
}

public int getCurrentOrderSerial() {
    return currentOrderSerial;
}

public void setCurrentOrderSerial(int currentOrderSerial) {
    this.currentOrderSerial = currentOrderSerial;
}
}
```

The XML code of the AddressFragment:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/app_main_bg"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="@string/address_fragment_title"
        android:textColor="@color/pureBlack"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/numWarning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/number_warning"
        android:textColor="@color/img_warning"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/name_field"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameField"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:hint="@string/name_field" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/phone_field"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneField"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:hint="@string/phone_field" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/areaField"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/area_field" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/address_fragment_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_location"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addressField"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:hint="@string/address_fragment_title" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/details_field"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_details"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/detailsField"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:hint="@string/details_field" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/confirmCV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="18dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/card_view_bg"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@string/order_now"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_confirm" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="@string/order_now"
                android:textColor="@color/pureWhite"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

     </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

 </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>


 here my JSON::
 {
 "23" : {
  "currentOrderSerial" : 2,
 "orderNo: 2" : {
   "serialNo: 1" : {
     "name" : "napa Extra",
     "piece" : 200
   }
 }
 }
 }
```

[I use phone number as primary Identifier for every user. That's why phone numbers must be required.]
Please help to fix this...
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You've included pictures of your code and the JSON tree in your question. Please replace then with the actual code and JSON as text. The latter you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes then searchable, allows us to easily use it to test and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Likely not calling `.push()`, then it will overwrite.

Comment: I updated my question... please take a look and solve this.

Comment: in your `setOrderSerial`, can you make sure the `orderNo` in `OrderSerial osObject = new OrderSerial(orderNo);` is correct? or show us your OrderSerial object

Comment: please take a look now..